# Navigating between pages in wpf not working

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I've done the simplest thing. I open a new window and put a frame in it and I wanted to show in the frame a page.
The window code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Page1 p = new Page1();
        navigator.NavigationService.Navigate(p);
    }
}
```

navigator is the frame, in Page1 I have black background color to see the difference. When I run it I still see the window and not the page that should be inside the frame. Why isn't this working?

Window:[image]

Page:[image]

But i get the white one.

The code for page 1:

```
<Page x:Class="test.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="269" d:DesignWidth="292"
Title="Page1">

<Grid Background="Black">

</Grid>
```

In the cs side i didn't write anything.

Comment: What is the code for _page1_?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content property of the Page to something to be able to actually see it:

```
<Page x:Class="test.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="269" d:DesignWidth="292"
  Title="Page1">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <TextBlock>PAGE1</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

An empty black Grid is not visible but if you put a TextBlock in it you should be able to see it.

Comment: Please post the markup of Window1.xaml then because it certainly works for me.